# Good syntax for pathing inside [Code] of inno-setup

Tags: inno-setup

Here i have a problem with my inno-setup. Im trying to use the function `FileCopy` to overwrite a file, but i got a problem with the pathing. The structure of files inside my folder need to stay the same. To be clear, there is two folders inside my main folder: the first folder have my inno executable and on the second, there is the file i wanna copy. Since `FileCopy` need to have the absolute paths, i use {src} to have the path to my executable. The destination is always the same, so it doesnt matter.

The thing is, {src} give me the path to my executable, but **i need to go back of one level inside folder's tree** to go in the desired file's folder. Does anyone have an idea?

P.S. I cannot use the [Files] section because i need to overwrite a file automatically generated by one executable inside my [Run] section.

I tried this, but it seems like FileCopy doesnt handle it :

```
FileCopy(ExpandConstant('{src}\..\FilesFolder\MyFile.txt')
```

**EDIT**

As suggested, i added the following line to into my code to check the value expanded : `Log(ExpandConstant('{src}\..\112 - Source\Package\616279-003\SystemManager.exe.config'));`

And the result is what it is supose to be : `C:\Users\Adminitrator\MainFile\ExecutableFile\..\FilesFolder\MyFile.txt`

Comment: Your syntax is correct. The problem must be else where. Put `Log(ExpandConstant('{src}\..\FilesFolder\MyFile.txt'));` before the `FileCopy` and check the installer log to see what is expands to. Attach the result to your question together with the correct/expected path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, as wierd at it seems, i formatted the disk and tried it again and it worked. So for any person that is wondering, it seems like the syntax is indeed right.